# Appending a git commit in commit history

Tags: git, github, rebase

I've a commit (Lets call it ComV2) in the Dev branch that was made a month ago and is 10 commit behind the HEAD. However I need to make a build based on commit ComV2 but with a few changes to one of the files in that commit.

What I've tried so far:

1. Checkedout ComV2 - this resulted in getting a detached HEAD (that's normal)
2. Made changes in a file in commit ComV2
3. Stashed those changes.
4. Started git rebase with "edit" type for commit ComV1 (ComV1 is one commit earlier then ComV2)
5. Popped changes from the stash
6. Made a commit for the popped stash changes. Lets call this commit ComV2.1
7. Did git rebase --continue
8. Checked out ComV2.1 in a new branch. Lets call it TempBranch
9. Switched back to the Dev branch - This resulted in reattaching the HEAD to the latest commit
10. Merged TempBranch into Dev

**The Problem:**

This merge resulted in to the changes from the latest commits in Dev branch getting inserted into rest of the files from commit ComV2 that I don't want and the ComV2.1 is not after ComV2.1 in history. It's the latest commit according to git log. I also want this changed file to be added into the commits that are after ComV2.1

**Question:**

1. How can I make ComV2.1 to show up right after ComV2 and have the exact same code as ComV2 except for the file that I'm modifying in ComV2.1?
2. Is it a good practice to do this? (I'm the only one that's working on this project)

Comment: If no one else is using or ever has seen `Dev`, then you may try `git rebase -i HEAD~15`, then change `pick` to `edit` for the `ComV2` commit.  Then, when the rebase pauses you may fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the history of a publicly shared branch like `Dev` is usually not a good idea.  The reason why it is not a good idea is that it would cause confusion for anyone else who has checked out this branch and is currently using it.

A much safer option would be to `git revert` the `ComV2` commit via:

```
git revert <SHA-1 for ComV2>
```

Then, make whatever hotfix you need.  This option adds one or more new commits on top of the `HEAD` of the `Dev` branch, and is safe for all sharing the branch.

Comment: But then the latest changes will appear as the ComV2.1 and the changes that happened after ComV2 in history will not be there in ComV2.1 that's now the latest commit

Comment: There isn't much you can do without rewriting history.  The reality is that you had a bug in your codebase for some time.  Then you fixed it; nothing wrong or unusual about that story.  You _could_ try an interactive rebase, but if you have any merge commits between `ComV2` and the HEAD of your branch, you might have to redo the merges.